# The "error" dialog is very difficult to read

Tags: bug, design, error-message

So I was upvoting a comment on an answer, but the request seemed to fail for some reason. The error dialog is displayed, but I had to highlight the text to actually see what it was, it looks pretty ugly :)

[image]

The message I received was a "Network Error" (TCP) a communication error occured.

Comment: Does the same error occur in Internet Explorer?

Comment: @DogLover I can't reproduce the issue now unfortunately, but I actually experienced this on Chrome (I probably should have mentioned that).